# AWS Cost and Usage Reports and linked accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cost-management

I'm currently under an AWS Organisation Subscription. I want to export cost by CSV of my linked account into a S3 bucket.

I have rights on my account, I can use Cost Explorer, do Budgets, but I'm unable to do the Cost&Usage Report as shown in this screenshot : [image]

[The official doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cur/latest/userguide/detailed-billing.html) doesn't talk about this case. My question is 'Does the organisation account can enable the billing feature 'Cost and Usage Reports' 
for one linked account?' If not, is there a way to automate this export of CSV into a S3 bucket ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CUR (Cost and usage report) will be generated only in the billing account if you're under an organization. All you have to do is go to your billing account, and enable CUR from there. It's a simple process and the reports will be sent to the billing account S3. It is also best practice from security and isolation perspective.

Note that the link you sent is the DBR (Detailed billing report) and is considered legacy already.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cur/latest/userguide/what-is-cur.html

> If you use the consolidated billing feature in AWS Organizations, the Amazon S3 bucket that you designate to receive the billing reports must be owned by the master account in your organization. You can't receive billing reports in a bucket that is owned by a member account. If you use consolidated billing, you can also have your costs broken down by member account.

Comment: fwiw, CUR also seems to be "legacy" now...